# Open only one sub-menu at a time on clicking primary menu li>a

Tags: jquery, html

The PHP code outputs the HTML structure like this -

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="link">LINK 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 2 (has sub-menu)</a>     <!-- click disabled -->  
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">LINK 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">LINK 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 6 (has sub-menu)</a>     <!-- click disabled -->
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">LINK 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">LINK 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">LINK 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 11</a></li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery to open `sub-menu` on click is like this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var li = $('.menu>li',this).has('.sub-menu');
    $('>a',li).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(e.target).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

This is the working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbac7tdt/)**.

What I'm trying to achieve is that only one `.sub-menu` must be open at any moment. That is, if one `.sub-menu` is already opened, then clicking to open the 2nd `.sub-menu` must close the previous `.sub-menu`. How can i modify the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var li = $('.menu>li',this).has('.sub-menu');
        $('>a',li).click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $(e.target).next().toggle();

           $(e.target).parent().siblings().find("ul.sub-menu:visible").hide();
    });
});
```

`$(e.target).parent().siblings().find("ul.sub-menu:visible").hide();` Traverses to the parent element, looks at it's siblings and finds any visible submenus and hides them

Answer (score 1):

Added code in the handler to close any open sub-menu before opening one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var li = $('.menu>li',this).has('.sub-menu');
    $('>a',li).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.sub-menu').hide();
        $(e.target).next().show();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbac7tdt/3/)